# AngularJs - RXJS Observable unsubscribe

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I have setup an RXJS observable. I have two components which subscribe to a subject in service factory. How do I unsubscribe a selected component to the subject so that a button is pressed it stops listening to the subject broadcast?

See my jsfiddle [Unsubscribe App](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/0maek0qr/)

My code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/boxa">
  BoxA - Message Listener: </br>
  <strong>{{boxA.msg}}</strong></br>
  <md-button ng-click='boxA.unsubcribe()' class='md-warn'>Unsubscribe A</md-button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/boxb">
    BoxB - Message Listener: </br>
  <strong>{{boxB.msg}}</strong></br>
  <md-button ng-click='boxB.unsubcribe()' class='md-warn'>Unsubscribe B</md-button>
 </script>

  <md-content class='md-padding'>
    <h3>
      {{name}}
    </h3>
    <label>Enter Text To Broadcast</label>
    <input ng-model='msg'/></br>
    <md-button class='md-primary' ng-click='broadcastFn()'>Broadcast</md-button></br>
    <h4>
    Components
    </h4>
    <box-a></box-a></br>
    <box-b></box-b>
  </md-content>

</div><!--end app-->


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,msgService) {

   $scope.name = "Observer App Example";
   $scope.msg = 'Message';
   $scope.broadcastFn = function(){
        msgService.broadcast($scope.msg);
   }   
});

app.component("boxA",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function(msgService) {
        var boxA = this;
        boxA.msgService = msgService;            
        boxA.msg = '';
        boxA.msgService.subscribe(function(obj) { 
            console.log('Listerner A');
          boxA.msg = obj;
                });
        boxA.unsubscribe=function(){

        };

      },
      controllerAs: 'boxA',
      templateUrl: "/boxa"
})
app.component("boxB",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function(msgService) {
        var boxB = this;
        boxB.msgService = msgService;            
        boxB.msg = '';
        boxB.msgService.subscribe(function(obj) { 
            console.log('Listerner B');
          boxB.msg = obj;
                });

        boxB.unsubscribe=function(){

        };
      },
      controllerAs: 'boxB',
      templateUrl: "/boxb"
})

app.factory('msgService', ['$http', function($http){
    var msgSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
    return{
        subscribe:function(subscription){
            msgSubject.subscribe(subscription);
        },
        broadcast:function(msg){
        console.log('success');
            msgSubject.onNext(msg);
        }
    }   
}])
```

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: Yes I did jfiddle here. Also answer below is similar. https://jsfiddle.net/499jhs9y/

Comment: Yeah, I found that `subscription.dispose()` did the trick.

Comment: The new RxJs 5 Beta now changed from `subscription.dispose()` to `subscription.unsubscribe()` Please refer to here [https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see updated fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0maek0qr/41/)

the `subscribe` function returns a `Disposable` to work with and you must first return the subscription from your factory (line 60):

```
subscribe: function(subscription){
    return msgSubject.subscribe(subscription);
}
```

This will let you store your subscription in each controller to work with in the future. (line 21 & 42)

```
var boxASubscription = boxA.msgService.subscribe(function(obj) {
    console.log('Listerner A');
    boxA.msg = obj;
});
```

You can then call the `dispose` method on the subscription when you want to unsubscribe:

```
boxA.unsubscribe = function(){
    console.log('Unsubscribe A');
    boxASubscription.dispose();
};
```

n.b.

For some reason I couldn't get your demo to work with `<md-button>` so I changed this to `<button>` for the sake of the demo.

Answer (score 14):

As per my comment above the new RxJs 5 Beta now changed from `subscription.dispose()` to `subscription.unsubscribe()` Please refer to here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe