# How to unsubscribe immediately after the the condition is met in RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am new to the RxJs observables and I am finding difficulty in unsubscribing the loop once the criteria are met, can you please help me

In the below function if anytime the code reaches the if block I wanted to unsubscribe the Observables

Before asking this questions I have gone through below questions and none of them helped me much

1. [Rxjs observable wait until some condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754771/rxjs-observable-wait-until-some-condition-is-met)
2. [AngularJs - RXJS Observable unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129726/angularjs-rxjs-observable-unsubscribe)

**Javascript Function**

```
this.router.events.subscribe((url: any) => {
    url = this.router.url;
    if ((url === "/profile" || url === "/summary") && this.filterConfigFlag === false) {

        /*
        Perform operations
        */

    } else {
        console.log(typeof (url), url);

    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to run the `next` handler and complete the Observable right after that?

Comment: @martin that's true if that matches I want to go ahead

Comment: What do you mean by "go ahead". Continue receiving more items or complete?

Comment: @martin I want to complete it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably want `takeWhile`:

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(url => url === ...), // when the condition isn't met it'll complete immediately
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

but if you want to include also the last value (the value that completed the Observable) you'll need to do something like this:

#### Before RxJS 6.4

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    concatMap(url => url === ... ? of(url, null) : of(url)),
    takeWhile(Boolean),
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

#### Since RxJS 6.4

RxJS 6.4 added an overload to `takeWhile`, it is now possible to include the last value like this:

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(url => url === ..., true),
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Here is the docs link for further reference: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html

Comment: It doesn't work, subscription never fired in my case. I tried the same code

Comment: takeWhile doesn't complete the observable, so it doesn't unsubscribe it

Answer (score 2):

You may make use of a `Subject` and `takeUntil` operator as follows:

```
unsubscribe = new Subject<any>();

this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(unsubscribe)).subscribe((url: any) => {
    url = this.router.url;
    if ((url === "/profile" || url === "/summary") && this.filterConfigFlag === false) {

        /*
        Perform operations
        */
this.unsubscribe.next();
    } else {
        console.log(typeof (url), url);
this.unsubscribe.next();
    }
});
```